# How to remove mammography tag artifacts

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I have a mammography image dataset (mini DDSM). These images show letter artifacts indicating left or right mamma and other useless information for my ML model, so I want to curate this dataset before training the model.

In this paper, [Preprocessing of Digital Mammogram Image Based on
Otsu’s Threshold](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/235050425.pdf), they use Otsu's binarization and opening on the mammography to clean the image (page 5 of 10):

[Their results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEyTZ.jpg)

So far, I have coded this:

```
im = io.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/TFM/DDSMPNG/ALL2/0.jpg')

# thresholding
thresh = im > filters.threshold_otsu(im)

# opening with a disk structure
disk = morphology.disk(5)
opened = morphology.binary_opening(thresh,disk)

# plotting

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))

plt.subplot(131)
plt.imshow(im,cmap='gray')
plt.subplot(132)
plt.imshow(opened,cmap='gray')

plt.imsave('/content/drive/MyDrive/TFM/DDSMPNG/Blackened/0.jpg',opened)
```

And these are the plots:

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnbnC.jpg)

I have also tried with a higher disk shape to do the opening, it seems to remove more white of the small letter artifact, but also crops a bit the mammography:

```
disk = morphology.disk(45)
opened = morphology.binary_opening(thresh,disk)
```

The result:

[Result with disk shape (45,45)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrFIF.jpg)

I guess I will have to create some kind of mask with the binarization and apply it to the original image, but I am new to image processing libraries and I'm not sure how to achieve the results

EDIT 1: I tried @fmw42 suggestion and I have some issues with it (I work on Google Colab, dont know If it has something to do...):

First, with the image used as example on your code, it doesn't seem to work propperly, don't know why, I copied your code and just modified the path to the image as well as some subplots to see the results:

```
# read image
img = cv2.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/TFM/DDSMPNG/ALL2/0.jpg')
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# apply otsu thresholding
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU )[1] 

# apply morphology close to remove small regions
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5,5))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# apply morphology open to separate breast from other regions
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5,5))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

# get largest contour
contours = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# draw largest contour as white filled on black background as mask
mask = np.zeros((hh,ww), dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(mask, [big_contour], 0, 255, cv2.FILLED)

# dilate mask
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (55,55))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)

# apply mask to image
result = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

# save results

cv2.imwrite('/content/drive/MyDrive/TFM/DDSMPNG/Blackened/0.jpg', result)

# show resultls

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))

plt.subplot(141)
plt.imshow(thresh,cmap='gray')
plt.subplot(142)
plt.imshow(morph,cmap='gray')
plt.subplot(143)
plt.imshow(mask,cmap='gray')
plt.subplot(144)
plt.imshow(result,cmap='gray')
```

Results:

[image]

Second, for the rest of the images, it seems to work well for most of them, but it crops a bit the breast surface:

[image]

In your result image, it seems to be much more smooth, how can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT 2: @fmw42 solution works fine, if someone has the same issue, you only need to play with the kernel sizes of the morphological filters until the image behaves like his results on the answer.

Thank you so much!

Comment: They used connected components to filter out the smaller regions and keep only the breast region. You can do the same or easier to get contours and filter out all but the largest contour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way to process your image in Python/OpenCV.

```
 - Read the input
 - Convert to grayscale
 - Otsu threshold
 - Morphology processing
 - Get largest contour from external contours
 - Draw all contours as white filled on a black background except the largest as a mask and invert mask
 - Apply the mask to the input image
 - Save the results
```

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread("mammogram.png")
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# apply otsu thresholding
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU )[1] 

# apply morphology close to remove small regions
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5,5))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# apply morphology open to separate breast from other regions
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5,5))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

# apply morphology dilate to compensate for otsu threshold not getting some areas
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (29,29))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)

# get largest contour
contours = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
big_contour_area = cv2.contourArea(big_contour)

# draw all contours but the largest as white filled on black background as mask
mask = np.zeros((hh,ww), dtype=np.uint8)
for cntr in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cntr)
    if area != big_contour_area:
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [cntr], 0, 255, cv2.FILLED)
    
# invert mask
mask = 255 - mask

# apply mask to image
result = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('mammogram_thresh.jpg', thresh)
cv2.imwrite('mammogram_morph.jpg', morph)
cv2.imwrite('mammogram_mask.jpg', mask)
cv2.imwrite('mammogram_result.jpg', result)

# show resultls
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('morph', morph)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thresholded Image:

[image]

Morphology Processed Image:

[image]

Mask Image From Contours:

[image]

Result Image:

[image]

**Alternate**

```
- Read the input
- Convert to grayscale
- Otsu threshold
- Morphology processing
- Get largest contour from external contours
- Draw largest as white filled on black background as a mask 
- Dilate mask
- Apply the mask to the input image
- Save the results
```

Input:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread("mammogram.png")
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# apply otsu thresholding
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU )[1] 

# apply morphology close to remove small regions
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5,5))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# apply morphology open to separate breast from other regions
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5,5))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

# get largest contour
contours = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# draw largest contour as white filled on black background as mask
mask = np.zeros((hh,ww), dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(mask, [big_contour], 0, 255, cv2.FILLED)

# dilate mask
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (55,55))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)

# apply mask to image
result = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('mammogram_thresh.jpg', thresh)
cv2.imwrite('mammogram_morph2.jpg', morph)
cv2.imwrite('mammogram_mask2.jpg', mask)
cv2.imwrite('mammogram_result2.jpg', result)

# show resultls
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('morph', morph)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Threshold Image:

[image]

Morphology Processed Image:

[image]

Mask Image:

[image]

Result:

[image]

**ADDITION**

Here is the second method of processing applied to your larger JPG image. I noted that it was about 6x in width and height. So I increased the morphology kernels by about 6x from 5 to 31. I also trimmed the image borders 40 pixels all around and then added back a black border of the same amounts.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread("mammogram.jpg")
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# shave 40 pixels all around
gray = gray[40:hh-40, 40:ww-40]

# add 40 pixel black border all around
gray = cv2.copyMakeBorder(gray, 40,40,40,40, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=0)

# apply otsu thresholding
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU )[1] 

# apply morphology close to remove small regions
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (31,31))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# apply morphology open to separate breast from other regions
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (31,31))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

# get largest contour
contours = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# draw largest contour as white filled on black background as mask
mask = np.zeros((hh,ww), dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(mask, [big_contour], 0, 255, cv2.FILLED)

# dilate mask
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (305,305))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)

# apply mask to image
result = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('mammogram_thresh.jpg', thresh)
cv2.imwrite('mammogram_morph2.jpg', morph)
cv2.imwrite('mammogram_mask2.jpg', mask)
cv2.imwrite('mammogram_result2.jpg', result)

# show resultls
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('morph', morph)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Threshold Image:

[image]

Morphology Image:

[image]

Mask Image:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is awesome!! Thank you so much, I will try it as soon as I can get to my PC.

Comment: Hello again, please look at the edit of the post with some comments on your code :D

Comment: Basically, the morphology filters doesn't seem to work :S

Comment: I posted two different solutions. The first solution has aliased edges. The second solution should be better but may also show some aliasing, but outside the breast. Look carefully at the differences in the two solutions. You can also anti-alias the mask to make the edges smoother. But I do not think you can avoid it altogether. If the aliasing is outside the breast and the tags are gone, then this satisfies your request to get rid of the tags.

Comment: I see, and about the first problem, that both solutions dont work with the image you used as example? When I copied your code to test it, worked fine in other mammographies but not that one, it doesn’t get rid of the tags...

Comment: Did you start with the image I used or your version of it? Check each intermediate step result by viewing and see if it matches what I posted. If not, report where it failed.

Comment: It works fine with your version of the image, the one in .png. I tried the code with my own version in .jpg, because they are lighter and easier to upload to Google Drive and train my NN with them. How can I fix this? Maybe PNG have different dimension shapes and this  'hh, ww = img.shape[:2]' isn't working?

Comment: The first method fails on the morph filters, it doesn't dilate the contours like in your morph filters' results, The second method fails on the mask result, where it should be just the breast contour, in my result both are still present.

Comment: What version of Python, OpenCV?

Comment: OpenCV: 4.1.2
Python: Python 3.7.10

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231584/discussion-between-fmw42-and-luis-garcia-tiscar).

Comment: I can edit the dilate kernel size of the first method from (29,29) to (157,157) and it dilates the jpg propperly, but the two contours are connected and it doesnt extract the biggest contour in order to create the mask only with the smallest contour belonging to the tag...

Comment: I have processed your JPG image and posted that as an ADDITION in my answer above. It processed just fine after increasing the morphology kernels by the scale factor of the images

Comment: Results are awesome! Thank you so much again!